# Will completing Dawnguard stop Vampire Attacks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Windhelm has had more Vampire Attacks than Whiterun which i have been in the most and i thinkl they're messing up the game as when i arrived to do the quest about "The Butcher", after killing the vampires i went to where the dead body was about however only 3 people where there and no guard came running up to me, one of the casualties of the Vampire Attack was a Windhelm Guard.

Given that i am also roleplaying in the game and have joined the Stormcloaks these attacks on Ulfric's City are unforgivable  so i am wondering, if i complete the Dawnguard quest line will these vampire attacks stop?